# Restart this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, startup, restart

What code do I have to write to restart this script? I want to totally reset / update the script via a code in order to let it process new / updated information. Maybe best way to just stop it and start it again. But how?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _myplug = _myplug || {};
_myplug.key = '12e9u349u43098j8r940rjciocjo';
_myplug.renderTo = '';
window.myplug||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=myplug=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
    c.src='js/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

Comment: Well this script is loading another script "loader.js" -- presumably loader.js is doing all the work, you'd have to see what that script is creating and doing in order to "undo" it or re-initialize it. That file will be creating objects and functions in memory that you won't easily be able to "restart" unless the script explicitly has functionality that allows you to re-init.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing enough info about the script, here's a hacky method that will be sure to reload the script:

```
 function reloadScript() {
  with(document) {
   var newscr = createElement('script');
   newscr.id = 'reloadMe';
   newscr.appendChild(createTextNode(getElementById('reloadMe').innerHTML));
   body.removeChild(getElementById('reloadMe'));
   body.appendChild(newscr);
  }
 }
```

You'll need an ID on your script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="reloadMe">
```

**UPDATE:**

The above method isn't enough to refresh your code, because your code also appends another script tag in the document, called `loader.js`.

Here's a special version for your situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="notTheScriptYouWannaRefresh">
var _myplug = _myplug || {};
_myplug.key = '12e9u349u43098j8r940rjciocjo';
_myplug.renderTo = '';
window.myplug||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=myplug=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';
    c.async=true;c.id='reloadMe';   //<-- CUSTOM ID SET!
    c.src='js/loader.js?';d.body.appendChild(c);
})(document);

 function reloadScript() {
  with(document) {
   var newscr = createElement('script');
   newscr.id = 'reloadMe';
   newscr.appendChild(createTextNode(getElementById('reloadMe').innerHTML));
   body.removeChild(getElementById('reloadMe'));
   body.appendChild(newscr);
  }
 }

 window.setTimeout(reloadScript, 10000); //Reload after 10 seconds
</script>
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not what I search for. The script is not resetted or restarted, so I further investigate what causes this. Maybe that comment from you about loader.js is the clue. When I find out I will post it here. Coding seems to be more difficult than you sometimes wanted. Just STOP script and START! How simple....

Comment: Remove the `window.myplug||` from `window.myplug||(function(d) {`

Comment: I appreciate your help. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything when I change the codes as you suggested. Thanks BTW.

Comment: About your comment "Hope this solves the problem. (If it doesn't, reload loader.js as well?)".
How to reload loader.js. I don't have much knowledge about Jquery / Javascript Syntax. I found it a good suggestion and want to try that. Perhaps the syntax would not be too difficult?

Comment: @Cinzel added some code for your loader.js situation

Answer (score 0):

I know something more.

I found another method, which maybe does the same as what @AaronGillion suggested. Only the trigger differs (it restarts every x seconds).

This is the method:

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LPFYB/

I replaced the `scriptTag.innerText` with my script codes. Since I see that this starts my script succesfully, I also understand that the script is removed and reinserted every x seconds. And since this doesn't update the script, it proves that there is another thing loaded that keeps the script continuing in the old state. Might be the loader.js.
Unfortunately my JS knowledge is limited. How to restart loader.js from my code?
For clarity I paste the code from this topic again below, including the loader.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _myplug = _myplug || {};
_myplug.key = '12e9u349u43098j8r940rjciocjo';
_myplug.renderTo = '';
window.myplug||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=myplug=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
    c.src='js/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

Question is how to restart loader.js.

Comment: `scriptTag.innerText` won't work in Firefox. Mozilla uses `scriptTag.textContent` instead. // Check my updated answer, I made my code work for your loader.js situation!